# Quotes in a long multi-variable SQL request in Basic4android

Tags: sql, quote, basic4android

All B2A users.

Again about double quotes in SQL: how to be (replace quotes) in B2A long SQL INSERT\UPDATE request string, if this string is created dinamically, fields names and qty are variables (download by HTTP), and any value of them can be a string with quotes ?
Fields values are also in double quotes for INSERT, and I mean that whole the big SQL string cannot be easy formatted as string with & QUOTE & parts.

B4A gives SQLite exception "sintax error". Quotes in the values must be saved\used.... :-( not to be replaced by two single quotes.
What more symbols in the fields values must be specially checked (excepting destructive SQL injections...)?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use parameterized queries with ExecQuery2 or ExecNonQuery2. [SQL docs](http://www.basic4ppc.com/android/help/sql.html#sql).
You can also use [DBUtils](http://www.basic4ppc.com/forum/showthread.php?p=47359).